# CSV to MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

While submitting file i get this error-

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Name,Short Description,Description,Address,Phone,Email,Category)
>   VALUES(,,,,,,)' at line 1)

I Tried everything but still my code not working perfectly. Below is my php code-

```
<div id="form">        
    <?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("mysql6.000webhost.com","username","password");
    mysql_select_db("a7611052_123",$connect); //select the table 
    //Connect to Database
    $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE tablename";
    //empty the table of its current records
    mysql_query($deleterecords);
    //Upload File
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
    echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
    readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
    }

    //Import uploaded file to Database
    $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $Bn=$data[0];
    $Sd=$data[1];
    $D=$data[2];
    $A=$data[3];
    $P=$data[4];
    $E=$data[5];
    $C=$data[6];
    $import="INSERT INTO BusinessD(Business Name,Short Description,Description,Address,Phone,Email,Category) VALUES($Bn,$Sd,$D,$A,$P,$E,$C)";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    fclose($handle);
    print "Import done";
    //view upload form
    }else {
    print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";
    print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='B.php' method='post'>";
    print "File name to import:<br />\n";
    print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";      
    print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";
    }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please try not to use mysql_connect instead use `mysqli_connect` or `PDO_MySQL` read this->http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated Also do not provide your real `username/password` credentials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your Insert query as

```
INSERT INTO BusinessD(`Business Name`,`Short Description`,`Description`,`Address`,`Phone`,`Email`,`Category`) VALUES('$Bn','$Sd','$D','$A','$P','$E','$C')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes:

```
$import="INSERT INTO BusinessD('Business Name','Short Description','Description','Address','Phone','Email','Category') VALUES($Bn,$Sd,$D,$A,$P,$E,$C)";
```